# Remote Access -> Connected App - App has dissapeared

Tags: connected-apps, remote-access

I originally had a "Remote Access" app in a developer org.  I am still using this today to log Cases's via a web form.  I wanted to make a few changes and I can't find it via Setup...I have checked the Connected Apps section under Create -> Apps and the alternative under Manager -> Apps with no joy.  I have also searched for Remote Access and I can't seem to find it.

I can see it "exists" as the Login History shows the App's access to the Org.

Anyway - can anyone shed some light on where the App can be found?

Comment: Is this local or part of package??

Comment: Local - no packages/apps installed in this org

Comment: Do you have **customize application** permission on your profile??

Comment: Thanks  and yes  :(  Is there anyway to find it via SOQL?  I plan on using the force.com IDE tomorrow to see if I can find it with that (I couldn't with Octopus)

Comment: Yes it is possible.Writing it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find it through SOQL as well.It's the [ConnectedApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_connectedapplication.htm) object.

SOQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM ConnectedApplication
```

**From Comments:**

To **read** connected apps one must have **customize application** permission.For more information refer this [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_overview.htm)

**Edit:**

[Remote Access applications have been replaced by connected apps](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_about.htm&language=en)

So i think my solution is still valid.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't display anything - can you advise the SOQL for remoteaccess?  I have tried again and the login history still shows the app...just can't find it in the org :(

Comment: What do you mean by remoteaccess?? I'm assuming that you are running this query from the developer console in the org which have or had the connected app ??

Comment: Hi, this is what I mean by remoteaccess: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_about.htm&language=en.  That is how it was originally set up, actually using this: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API

Comment: Thanks for the help - except - my question/problem is basically I can't find the "app"?  As remote access is deprecated I can't find it there and it hasn't displayed under Connected Apps...how can I view the app/change the settings etc.  I know I could simply create a new one but I want to cover all my bases with this old one first - is it a bug it hasn't become available in connected apps?

Comment: You have to consider the fact that connected app can be deleted.Apart from permissions i think that could only be the reason.You should try to contact support.Maybe they can help you.